# How to format YAML to specify which model to populate using yaml_db gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, yaml, populate

I'm pretty new to this, so this is probably obvious and I'm missing something. If I have some data in a .yml file I want to populate the database with using yaml_db. How does it know what model to populate with the data? Do I name the file after the model (e.g. to populate people, person.yml) or should the data be nested under the name of the model (e.g. person: alan: etc, etc) , or something else?

Comment: Do you have a database with any data in it (even a little)? If so, try `rake db:data:dump` and look at the format of the resulting `db/data.yml` file to see what format it uses to specify the model. I haven't used the `yaml_db` gem, but I'm guessing this will get you a lot closer to an answer.

Comment: Thanks! Knew it would be something I should've thought of myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it thanks to normalocity's suggestion. For a Human model with a name, populating with 4 people would have YAML like this:

```
---
humans:
  columns:
  - id
  - name
  records:
  - - 1
    - "Billy"
  - - 2
    - "Joey"
  - - 3
    - "Sara"
  - - 4
    - "Jess"
```